# HTML Button Focus

Tags: html, cordova

Hi I am developing a web app for mobile. I am facing a problem like when user click on the button it showing some blue color kind when click happens. I would like to remove that focus when click happens. Can any one of you suggest me? blur() is not working in mobile devices,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

we can't remove that focus with css.it's html behavior on mobile devices.so we have to go for either senchatouch or Jquery for mobile

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know anything about Phonegap but if it is HTML/CSS link styled to look like a button you can use the CSS pseudo-selectors :link, :visited, :hover and :active.